# React, load new page on button click

Tags: reactjs, components, react-router

I have a simple react app with one route that latter renders 'List' component and that 'List' component renders a lot of 'Contact' components. Let’s say I have a phonebook and each contact is a new component. Now I want that when I click on one of the contacts to be taken to a complete new page with new route '/details' where I would see the details about that contact and where I would have a back button that goes back to the 'List' component. How would I do that? I am using react router v3

```
<Route path='/' component={PhoneBook} />
```

Comment: `<Link to='/details'>Click here</Link>`. Put that in your actual list. It works like an `<a>` tag. Though having one component for each contact sounds weird. You probably want to have *one* component, but send in different props depending on which one you click (eg: name, address, or whatever).

Comment: Isn't link just gonna tek me to a new page? How do I pass the data , props or something to identify the contact that was clicked on so it shows me the details about that contact?